# Does startAnimation() have threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I think an Android animation has to be in a thread like `runOnUiThraead()`. But when I code an animation without a thread it's OK. It doesn't throw any errors or exceptions. So, I wonder, does `startAnimation()` have a thread?

Do I keep coding animation without a thread?

Comment: If you write code without any thread then it runs on default thread with is the main thread and the UI thread. So, no need to put `runOnUiThread` because it is the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you can do it by define method

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // ...
    }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        // ...

        startAnimation();
        return true;
    }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        // ...
    }        
    return false;
}
public void run(){
    int start = (int)mMainData.getY();
    int end   = (int)mTargetData.getY();

    mScroller.startScroll(0, start, 0, -Math.round(mMainData.getY() - end), 500);

    while(canAnimate()){
        while(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
            mMainData.setY(mScroller.getCurrY());
            postInvalidate();
        }
        stopAnimation();
    }
}
private void startAnimation(){
    mThread = new Thread(this);
    mThread.start();
}
private void stopAnimation(){
    animate = false;
}
private boolean canAnimate(){
    return animate == true;
}
```